# Sorting filepaths by extension in python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I want to sort this list in a way that .log should be the first file and .gz file should be in a descending order

```
my_list = [
     '/abc/a.log.1.gz',
     '/abc/a.log',
     '/abc/a.log.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.30.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.2.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.5.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.3.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.6.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.4.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.12.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.10.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.8.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.14.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.29.gz'
]
```

Expected Result:

```
my_list = ['/abc/a.log',
        '/abc/a.log.gz',
        '/abc/a.log.30.gz',
        '/abc/a.log.29.gz',
        '/abc/a.log.29.gz',
        '/abc/a.log.14.gz',
        '/abc/a.log.12.gz',
        '/abc/a.log.10.gz',
        '/abc/a.log.8.gz',
        '/abc/a.log.6.gz',
        '/abc/a.log.5.gz',
        '/abc/a.log.4.gz',
        '/abc/a.log.3.gz',
        '/abc/a.log.2.gz'
        '/abc/a.log.1.gz']
```

My solution:
import os

```
def get_sort_keys(filepath):
    split_file_path = os.path.splitext(filepath)
    sort_key = (split_file_path[1], *os.path.splitext(split_file_path[0]))
    return (sort_key[0], sort_key[1], int(sort_key[2].strip(".")) if sort_key[2] else 0)

print(sorted(my_list, key=get_sort_keys, reverse=True))
```

Getting error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'log'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sorted` with a custom function that does some try-except checking.

```
def try_convert(x):
    y = x.rsplit('.', 2)[-2]
    return ('log' not in x, int(y) if y.isdigit() else float('inf'), x)

sorted(my_list, key=try_convert, reverse=True)

['/abc/a.log.gz',
 '/abc/a.log',
 '/abc/a.log.30.gz',
 '/abc/a.log.29.gz',
 '/abc/a.log.14.gz',
 '/abc/a.log.12.gz',
 '/abc/a.log.10.gz',
 '/abc/a.log.8.gz',
 '/abc/a.log.6.gz',
 '/abc/a.log.5.gz',
 '/abc/a.log.4.gz',
 '/abc/a.log.3.gz',
 '/abc/a.log.2.gz',
 '/abc/a.log.1.gz']
```

The function ensures that filenames without the integer component are to be ordered last (first, if you sort in descending). Additionally, all ".log" files come first.

Comment: I have edited question, could you please update your answer accordingly?

Comment: @user15051990 I can get you a solution that has the first and second list items interchanged. Is this ok?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to pass the string `'log'` into `int()`.

It cant then convert this to an `int` and raises `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'log'`

This is happening in here `return (sort_key[0], sort_key[1], int(sort_key[2].strip(".")) if sort_key[2] else 0)`

Try using a try catch block on the conversion

Answer (score 1):

Or use:

```
>>> sorted(my_list,key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[2]) if x.split('.')[2].isdigit() else 31,reverse=True)
['/abc/a.log.gz', '/abc/a.log.30.gz', '/abc/a.log.29.gz', '/abc/a.log.14.gz', '/abc/a.log.12.gz', '/abc/a.log.10.gz', '/abc/a.log.8.gz', '/abc/a.log.6.gz', '/abc/a.log.5.gz', '/abc/a.log.4.gz', '/abc/a.log.3.gz', '/abc/a.log.2.gz', '/abc/a.log.1.gz']
>>>
```

**Updated question:**

```
>>> sorted(my_list,key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[-2]) if x.split('.')[-2].isdigit() else 31,reverse=True)
['/abc/a.log', '/abc/a.log.gz', '/abc/a.log.30.gz', '/abc/a.log.29.gz', '/abc/a.log.14.gz', '/abc/a.log.12.gz', '/abc/a.log.10.gz', '/abc/a.log.8.gz', '/abc/a.log.6.gz', '/abc/a.log.5.gz', '/abc/a.log.4.gz', '/abc/a.log.3.gz', '/abc/a.log.2.gz', '/abc/a.log.1.gz']
>>>
```

Comment: I have updated the question can you please update the answer..\

Comment: @user15051990 Edited mine.